# Disk Partition on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, disk-space, disk-utility

I have a 750 GB hard disk and GB RAM. I will setup LAMP on my system.

Now my problem is, how I will make the disk partiton so that I will keep 300 GB for my localhost and the rest of memory will be divided into two parts so that I can keep documents in a drive and music in a drive.

Answer (score 0):

Use [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) - from a stand alone boot disc (or USB stick) which is a nice visual tool to resize and edit partitions.
Its also available as part of [SystemRescue boot disk](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage), a must have tool.

Comment: yes I know that..but what shall be the partition type?How the partition will be done for two different drives.

Comment: The Ubuntu partitions will be logical paritions under the same Extended partition. First reduce the existing parition within this extended parition, and then create the 2nd parition, also under the same extended partition. GParted will prompt for the type, and use the same type, either ext2 or ext3.

Answer (score 0):

When you are installing, choose manual partitioning.  Create your partitions and set the mount points.  The system partition needs mounted in the root ( / ).  Your two partitions for music and documents you could mount in /media/documents and /media/music.

Generally though, dividing up partitions is not recommended because sooner or later, you end up having one that is full and you can't add any more files there, but there's plenty of free space on the other partition.

Comment: so all the files should be placed inside `/home` or `/`

Comment: @user159377, I suggest you just put them somewhere in your home folder, yes.  By default there's a folder there within easy reach of the desktop for Documents, and another for Music already.  No need to partition the drive up.

Comment: By searching over Google I got this type of partion for 200 gb drive like this ` =======Primary==ext4======
/Boot- 2GB
swap- Double of RAM
/-150GB
===== Logic=============
/home-8o Gb
/var-`.So is this correct?

Comment: @user159377, there's no reason to have separate partitions for /boot or /var.  There is very little reason for /home.  Why don't you just accept the default install which just uses one partition for the root, and one for swap?